# How do i decrease the time period from 3 hours to 1 hour or lower in pvlib GFS() model forecasting

Tags: python, forecast, pvlib

I have been looking at the source code to see if it is possible to get more detailed forecasting from the library, as I need the weather data to forecast at least 1-hour duration. Currently, the library is able to provide me with a 3 hour time period but I require it to be 1 hour or lower.
Kindly let me know if there is a way to do it, any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation of the data source from which pvlib obtains data. The GFS data is available at 1 hour intervals through NOAA NOMADS. [solarforecastarbiter-core](https://github.com/SolarArbiter/solarforecastarbiter-core) contains a command line script to download and parse that data into netcdf4 files tailored to PV forecasting, as well as functions to read those files and convert into PV forecasts using pvlib. `solarforecastarbiter` is better than `pvlib.forecast` in every way except that it is significantly more complicated.